# Condition in the middle or at the tail of a chain

Tags: ruby

It is easy to have a condition at the head of a chain and share the rest:

```
if condition
    get_this
else
    get_that
end
.foo.bar.baz
```

But often, I want a condition in the middle or at the tail of a chain. The best I can think of is using `instance_eval`:

```
foo.bar
.instance_eval{
    if condition
        get_this
    else
        get_that
    end
}
.baz
```

But I have concern that calling `instance_eval` is heavy, so I actually end up not doing it. Is it worth doing so? Is there a better way, or should I just simply write:

```
if condition
    foo.bar.get_this
else
    foo.bar.get_that
end
.baz
```

Comment: +1 for the syntax in the first snippet.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Thanks for the comment, but what do you mean by "first snippet"?

Comment: A snippet is a small piece of code. I'm referring to the `if condition ... .foo.bar.baz` one. Snippet a diminutive of "snip", according to [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snippet). "Snip" itself is probably onomatopoeia, which in Japanese is apparently チョキチョキ.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I know the word. I didn't understand what you meant in the context. So, just directly continuing the chain after the condition is already good enough of a syntax?

Comment: Yes. I've seen `foo = (condition)`, but not `(condition).foo.bar.baz` before.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1797189/498594

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10110969/498594) for a general purpose solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not provide a method on `bar` which accepts a boolean value and then acts accordingly? This encapsulates the logic and can even shield complex logic or multiple conditions, without getting too messy.

```
class Bar
  def get_what(condition)
    case condition
      when qux; get_this(param1)
      when quux; get_that(param1, param2)
      else get_other(param1)
    end
  end
end

# assuming `bar` is an instance of `Bar`
foo.bar.get_what(cond).baz
```

PS: Depending on the use case I often try to avoid stuff like overly long message chains (because according to the [Law of Demeter (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) this might be considered bad practice :)), though when working with hashes and arrays in ruby it's kind of useful. So I suppose you have a valid use case for using a long message chain.

Answer (score 3):

How about using [Object#send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send) to conditionally call a method:

```
foo.bar.send(condition? ? :get_this : :get_that).baz
```

In a more complicated case, with multiple/different parameters one could use the [splat operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/918475/283608) to unwrap an array into parameters:

```
foo.bar.send(
  * case conditional
    when qux
      [:get_this, param1]
    when quux
      [:get_that, param1, param2]
    else
      [:get_other, param1, param2]
    end
).baz
```

Comment: I see. That partially solves the problem, i.e., when `get_this` and `get_that` are simplistic method (possibly with arguments). Can you also think of a way when they are more complicated? Your answer is a nice idea, though.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I mentioned as a simplistic (single) method. But sometimes, there are sequences of things to do separately under different conditions. But, your answer is nice.

Comment: Thanks. I think I would either need to do it like your answer or Iwe's answer.

Comment: Well, I answered from the control-flow POV in sync with the question tone. Of course, otherwise, when code gets heavy it's refactored into thin methods.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes a low-tech solution is the best:

```
my_bar = foo.bar
if condition
  my_thing = my_bar.get_this
else
  my_thing = my_bar.get_that
end
my_thing.baz
```

Seriously, I consider it far more important that the meaning of source code is 100% clear to everybody (including yourself some time in the future) than it being shortened by a line or two.

Comment: that's ok, but I think it's more idiomatic `my_thing = if condition...`

Comment: Maybe `my_thing = (condition ? ... : ...)`. Personally, there is no way I would ever use the value of an `if`, even though it technically is an expression.

Comment: In some cases, I think I need to do that.